# Limit by RAND without random order

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select records in order but limited randomly.

```
SELECT * FROM tm_winners WHERE paid_out=0 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT RAND(4,8)
```

However it seems I cannot have a random limit of rows. I am bassiclty trying to grab between 4 and 8 rows but NOT randomly, just limited randomly.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use a prepared statement to use a variable amount in the LIMIT clause.

```
SET @lrand = FLOOR(4 + RAND() * (8 - 4));
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * tm_winners WHERE paid_out=0 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @lrand;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, even if its not the cleanest way, Id set a var previous to the select statement and Limit by the var.

```
$randomVar = rand(4, 8);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tm_winners WHERE paid_out=0 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0,'.$randomVar;
```

Clearly if you wanted randomness within the actual results, you could clearly reintroduce the rand() within the statement

Hope it helps

Will